# GoogleMaps v2 Get Current Location On Emulator

Tags: java, android

Firstly, before I changed my code to get current location google maps worked fine on the emulator so my API key and google libraries and everything else to get the maps is setup correctly, now upon trying to get my current location even after sending GPS coordinates my app crashes with null pointer exception (I'm new to java and the error logging system sucks big time, every error is null exception like really now?? ..can't it return can't find last known location or something rather than null pointer?)

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setupMapIfNeeded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (googleMap == null){
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (googleMap !=null) {
            setUpMap();
        }

    }

}

private void setUpMap() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));
```

Mainfest:

```
    <permission
    android:name="com.twostarii.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.twostarii.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>    

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY KEY"/>
```

Activity:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Log:

```
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twostarii.googlemap/com.twostarii.googlemap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at com.twostarii.googlemap.MainActivity.setupMapIfNeeded(MainActivity.java:28)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at com.twostarii.googlemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-16 14:45:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1238):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is line 28 on `setUpMapIfNeeded()`?

Comment: How could you run GoolgeMap v2 on the emulator becouse it's not supported at all!!!!

Comment: @TalhaQ what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

`Activity`'s `onCreate()` gets called before the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` finishes. You need to wait until `onCreateView()` finishes to get a hold of your `Fragment` and its `GoogleMap`. For example, `onResume()` or `onStart()` in the `Activity` are good places to get a hold of your `Fragment`.

Also, `googleMap` will always be null here:

```
private void setupMapIfNeeded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (googleMap == null){


}
```

And will never be null here (once you move the code to `onStart()` or `onResume()`:

```
private void setupMapIfNeeded() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (...){
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (googleMap !=null) {
            setUpMap();
        }

    }

}
```

so no need for all the extra checks.